# sweertAlert2 closing the pop calls onConfirm method

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert2, cancel-button

I am using SweetAlert2 to alert the user. When I click on the confirm button the behavior is as expected, delete keyword call is made.

```
render: function() {
return(
<SweetAlert show={this.state.show} title="Context Processor"
                 text="Keyword deletion cannot be undone. Do you still want to continue?"
                onConfirm={this.deleteKeyword}
                showCloseButton={true}
                heightAuto={false}>
                </SweetAlert>
)},

deleteKeyword: function() {
        this.setState({show: false});
        this.props.deleteKeyword(this.state.keyword);
    },
```

However, when I simply close the alert box call is made then again! I went through the various options provided by the library - https://github.com/kessejones/react-sweetalert2/blob/master/src/ReactSweetAlert2.js but I couldn't find any of interest.
Also, added `showCloseButton` parameter but again when I click on it the delete keyword call is made.
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the method to `onConfirm={(e) => {this.deleteKeyword(e)}}` e tells me if it is confirmed or dismissed.